# How to show all threads on a specific CPU on Solaris?

Tags: unix, solaris, cpu-usage

Some process (or threads) is hammering CPU0 as you can see in **mpstat 30 2**

```
CPU minf mjf xcal  intr ithr  csw icsw migr smtx  srw syscl  usr sys  wt idl
  0    0   0    0    13    0    2    7    0  151    0  4250   99   1   0   0
  1  114   0    2   197   84 5220    5   10  109    0 10518   30   2   0  67
  2   79   0    1   184   83 5208    5    5   89    0  9788   30   2   0  68
  3   67   0    1   181   84 5150    5    4   87    0  9510   30   2   0  69
  4   53   0    3   171   72 12238    4    7  183    0 22214    3   3   0  94
  5   43   0    3   135    7  218    2    6   16    0   162    0   1   0  99
  6  110   0    2   172   79 4918    5    3  164    0  9553   34   2   0  64
  7  120   0    1   180   80 4873    4    4  194    0  9494   32   2   0  66
  8   53   0    1    23    2 28665    5    7  494    0 62023   12   9   0  79
  9   43   0    0    34    2 21469    6    8  676    0 58090   10  13   0  77
 10   59   0    1   210    2 33462    4    4  227    0 63500    7  16   0  78
 11   93   0    2 16940 16627 1261    2    6 1027    0  2043    0  10   0  90
 12   17   0    1    65    3   59    0    3    3    0    19    0   0   0 100
 13    6   0    1    89    4  104    0    3    2    0     9    0   0   0 100
 14    4   0   10    65    5   54    0    3    1    0    12    0   0   0 100
 15    4   0    1    66    6   56    0    3    2    0    21    0   0   0 100
 16    2   0    0    91   16   78    0    3    2    0    30    0   0   0 100
 17   17   0    1    80   15   70    0    4    2    0    79    0   0   0 100
 18   76   0    3 14946 14928   25    0    4   24    0   102    0   4   0  96
 19   57   0    0    20    2   17    0    3   15    0   107    0   0   0 100
 20   18   0    0    26    0   25    0    3   10    0    21    0   0   0 100
 21    0   0    0   106   70   46    0    3    4    0    40    0   1   0  99
 22   13   0    0    31    3   28    0    3    4    0    49    0   0   0 100
 23    0   0    0    35    5   24    0    3    5    0    54    0   0   0 100
```

but with **prstat -P0** only see the ndbmtd running wit around 15% on CPU0

```
   PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE  PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP       
 20028 root       77G   75G cpu0    40    0 8369:33:0  15% ndbmtd/44
   660 root     6200K 3700K sleep   59    0   0:00:53 0.0% inetd/4
   159 daemon   4540K 2408K sleep   59    0   0:00:09 0.0% kcfd/3
    11 root       11M   10M sleep   59    0   0:00:58 0.0% svc.configd/15
```

Is there a way to show all processes and treads on CPU0?

Comment: Probably a dupe:  http://serverfault.com/questions/299585/why-mysql-cluster-does-not-use-multiple-cores-of-the-cpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show all processes and threads (LWPs) on CPU0:

```
prstat -P0 -L
```